# What does a dollar sign followed by a number mean when calling g++?

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, gnu-make

I'm trying to make sense of a makefile but the gnu documentation is failing me. The following is a canned recipe. I can't make sense of $1, $2, $3, and they do not appear anywhere else in the code.

```
define make-depend-cpp
    g++ -MM -MF $3 -MP -MT $2 $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXDEFINES) $(INCLUDES)  $1
endef
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a macro defintion, and those are the arguements to the macro.  So if elsewhere in the Makefile you see:

```
$(call make-depend-cpp, file1, file2, file3)
```

it will get replaced with:

```
g++ -MM -MF file3 -MP -MT file2 $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXDEFINES) $(INCLUDES)  file1
```